# Streaming From Pi Camera Module

Tags: camera

I just got a new Pi camera module.  My Pi B+ is controlled through my Macbook.  I would like to stream to the Macbook without saving.  It seems that the standard vid command also saves.  Does anyone have a command that does not save?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess pistreaming is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/waveform80/pistreaming

Works exactly like you would like.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `raspivid` to stream without saving by telling it to write to `stdout` then redirecting that to something like netcat. There's some brief instructions on how to do this in the middle of the recipe "[Recording to a Network Stream](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.9/recipes1.html#recording-to-a-network-stream)" in the picamera docs (just search for "raspivid" and you'll find it - it's a couple of lines).

The [pistreaming project](https://github.com/waveform80/pistreaming) mentioned in Shak7's answer was my attempt at providing a streaming solution that would work more or less universally with web-browsers by not relying on them supporting HTML5 video features (it uses Dominic Szablewski's JavaScript MPEG1 decoder to avoid such dependencies). Because of this, it isn't very good quality and you'll find streaming H.264 directly from raspivid or picamera much better (although obviously you need something capable of playing the stream at the other end, like VLC).